# How to build a npm lib with subfolders like MateriaUI using Rollup.js

Tags: javascript, typescript, build, export, rollupjs

Im trying to build my lib and export the components like MaterialUI way:

[image: code screenshot]

But, the only thing I can do, is that:

[image: folder structure screenshot]

Im using rollup.js and typescript. I notice that d.ts and type.ts files have been exported in the component folder but the component itself is exported in main folder.

Can someone help me to fix it?

My rollup.js config:

```js
import commonjs from '@rollup/plugin-commonjs'
import resolve from '@rollup/plugin-node-resolve'
import replace from '@rollup/plugin-replace'
import peerDepsExternal from 'rollup-plugin-peer-deps-external'
import typescript from 'rollup-plugin-typescript2'
import postcss from 'rollup-plugin-postcss'
import { terser } from 'rollup-plugin-terser'
import del from 'rollup-plugin-delete'
import includePaths from 'rollup-plugin-includepaths'

/* css imports */

import pkg from './package.json'

export default {
  input: ['./src/index.ts', './src/TestComponent/index.tsx'],
  output: [
    {
      dir: 'dist/esm',
      format: 'esm',
      sourcemap: true,
      exports: 'named',
      strict: false,
      plugins: [terser()]
    }
  ],
  plugins: [
    includePaths({ paths: ['./src'] }),
    typescript({

    }),
    peerDepsExternal(),
    resolve(),
    commonjs(),
    del({
      targets: ['dist/*']
    }),
    postcss({
      modules: true,
      extract: false,
      namedExports: true,
      writeDefinitions: true,
    }),
    replace({
      preventAssignment: true,
      ENV: JSON.stringify(process.env)
    }),
  ],
  external: Object.keys(pkg.peerDependencies)
}
```

My tsconfig.json file:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "declaration": true,
    "declarationDir": "dist",
    "outDir": "dist",
    "module": "esnext",
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": ["es6", "dom", "es2016", "es2017"],
    "sourceMap": true,
    "allowJs": false,
    "jsx": "react",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noImplicitThis": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "plugins": [{ "name": "typescript-plugin-css-modules" }]
   },
  "include": ["src/**/*"],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "dist",
    "src/**/*.stories.tsx",
    "src/**/*.test.tsx"
  ]
 }
```

My folder's structure:

[image: folder structure screenshot]

Ps: I'd like to export only the components to import like

```js
import TestComponent from '@ind/package/esm/TestComponent'
```

**and**

```js
import {TestComponent} from '@ind/package/esm'
```

Answer (score 0):

Late reply, but for anyone stumbling on this the most straightforward way I found was to use the [`preserveModules`](https://rollupjs.org/guide/en/#outputpreservemodules) option: *Instead of creating as few chunks as possible, this mode will create separate chunks for all modules using the original module names as file names*.
It does respects the file's relative path, `components/Test.jsx` ends up in `dist/components/Test.js`.

This [issue](https://github.com/rollup/rollup/issues/2216) also suggests you can map things in `input` directly; but that doesn't seem to work when using `rollup` programmatically:

```js
export default {
    input: {
        'module1': 'src/module1.js',
        'foo/module2': 'src/foo/module2.js',
        'foo/bar/module3': 'src/foo/bar/module3.js',
   },
    output: {
        format: cjs,
        dir: 'dist'
    }
}
```

Comment: _> but that doesn't seem to work_


Yep, looks like [it shouldn't](https://rollupjs.org/configuration-options/#input), as follows in the docs:


`"Note that it is possible when using the object form to put entry points into different sub-folders by adding a / to the name. The following will generate at least two entry chunks with the names entry-a.js and entry-b/index.js, i.e. the file index.js is placed in the folder entry-b (...)"`